# Using Twitter Bootstrap, why is my div.container narrower than the one used on the Bootstrap website?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Compare

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html

to

http://saikono.com/

Both have div.container width set at 940px. Yet, the Bootstrap website is wider on my screen, which is what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using bootstrap.css while on twitter they are using bootsrap-responsive.css.

Comment: But when I inspect it in Firefox, they are using bootstrap.css. Is it possible that they use bootsrap-responsive but renamed it to bootstrap.css?

Comment: This answer is correct but its not properly worded. Both `bootstrap.css` and 'bootstrap-responsive.css' stylesheets need to be included for the responsive features of the bootstrap. Bootstrap.css first, responsive sheet second - loaded in that order on the head section of your page.