# Narrow Twitter Bootstrap container from Nu-get Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I install the twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 from nu-get.  The problem I'm facing is similar this one question which was asked previously:

[Using Twitter Bootstrap, why is my div.container narrower than the one used on the Bootstrap website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601707/using-twitter-bootstrap-why-is-my-div-container-narrower-than-the-one-used-on-t)

But unlike the answer to that question, I verified that in the method BootstrapBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(), both bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css are present as seen below.

```
public class BootstrapBundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/body.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-mvc-validation.css"
            ));
    }
}
```

So my question is why page looks narrow unlike the one from twitter bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html, and should I have done to fix?

Comment: Well, without seeing your page it's hard to say...

Comment: @Cheesemacfly, please refer to the other question that is mentioned.  The symptom is similar.

Comment: I would recommend opening up chrome inspector to see exactly what the style values are and from what file its coming from... other than that we're shooting in the dark here

Comment: @Khnle I know but since the other question didn't help you then your problem is certainly different